# Formatting Text

Tags: java

I need to format some text in JOptionPane.showMessageDialog. I need the text to be in tabular format
Example:

```
Operation           Result
  2 + 2               4
```

I have tried to use `string.format()` but it comes out ugly.  Any suggestions would be helpful.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`String.format` would work well if you were using a fixed-width font (like a console output) but the message dialogs default to a variable-width font.

Luckily all labels in Swing support HTML formatting. All you have to do is wrap your string with HTML tags like `<html> some text</html>`. Then you could use an actual HTML table.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you got some number of data to be displayed. Using JDialog instead of JOptionpane is better to put number of data. Answer to your question can be found in the below link

http://forums.techguy.org/software-development/1051819-solved-help-java-tabular-format.html

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a String containing the data in html code, you can try to do this format with a HTML table.